# Parsing data from tricky textfile using python - How do I place all relevant data on one line

Tags: python-3.x, text

I am relatively new to python, and in the middle of a project where by I have to extract forecast wind speed data from a poorly formatted text/NAVTEX file (~150000 lines) [Sample file](https://weather.gc.ca/marine/marine_bulletins_e.html?Bulletin=fqcn33.cyqx). I've managed to parse the date, the forecast regions but I am having trouble with the wind speed line "WND:" because in some cases it takes up more than one line, and others it does not:

```
NORTHEAST COAST: *<--- forecast region*
WNG: STORM / FREEZING SPRAY.
WND: NW25. 01/15Z S15. 02/00Z SE25. 02/12Z NE40. 02/18Z N50 LCLY G60 *<--- Wind speed line* 
ALONG THE COAST. *<--- Wind speed line* 
VIS: 02/00Z-03/03Z 0-1 SN.
```

I had the same issue with the forecast regions but managed to used the following piece of code to solve the issue:

```
lines = open(newfile,'r').readlines()
finalfile = open(final, 'w')
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if line.startswith("AND SOUTH:") or line.startswith("BANKS:"):
        lines[i-1] = lines[-1].strip() + line
        lines.pop(i)
    finalfile.write(line)
```

I tried to do something similar using "VIS:" as a keyword to place the "WND:"(wind speeds) on one line, but I am not getting the desired result:

```
lines = open(newfile,'r').readlines()
finalfile = open(final, 'w')
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if line.startswith("AND SOUTH:") or line.startswith("BANKS:"):
        lines[i-1] = lines[-1].strip() + line
        lines.pop(i)
    if line.startswith("VIS:"):
        if not lines[i-1].startswith("WND:") and lines[i-2].startswith("WND:"):
            lines[i-2] = lines[i-1].strip() + lines[i-1]
            lines.pop(i-1)
    finalfile.write(line)
```

My desired output is:

```
   NORTHEAST COAST: *<--- forecast region*
    WNG: STORM / FREEZING SPRAY.
    WND: NW25. 01/15Z S15. 02/00Z SE25. 02/12Z NE40. 02/18Z N50 LCLY G60 ALONG THE COAST. *<--- Wind speed line* 
    VIS: 02/00Z-03/03Z 0-1 SN.
```

From here I think I will be able to split up the wind speed line as I need it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will find every section with `WNG:` and then remove excessive newlines (variable `txt` is your string from the link in the question) ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Um7VJH/1)):

```
import re

def get_lines(txt):
    lines = iter(txt.splitlines())
    buf = next(lines, '')
    for line in lines:
        if ': ' in line:
            yield buf
            buf = line
        else:
            buf += ' ' + line
    if buf:
        yield buf

for wind_data in re.findall(r'([^\n]+:\nWNG:.*?)\n\n', txt, flags=re.S):
    for line in get_lines(wind_data):
        print(line)
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
EAST COAST-CAPE ST  FRANCIS AND SOUTH:
WNG: NIL.
WND: SW25 LCLY G35 ALONG THE COAST. 14/23Z SW25. 15/05Z SW15 XCPT SW25 OVER SOUTHERN SECTIONS. 15/11Z LGT XCPT W25 OVER SOUTHERN SECTIONS.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EAST COAST-NORTH OF CAPE ST  FRANCIS:
WNG: NIL.
WND: SW25 LCLY G35 ALONG THE COAST. 15/05Z SW15-20. 15/11Z VRB10-15. 15/17Z NW15-20.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NORTHEAST COAST:
WNG: NIL.
WND: SW15-20. 14/21Z VRB15. 15/02Z NW20. 15/23Z NW10-15.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FUNK ISLAND BANK:
WNG: NIL.
WND: SW25. 15/05Z S15-20. 15/17Z VRB10-15.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NORTHERN GRAND BANKS:
WNG: NIL.
WND: SW25. 15/02Z SW15-20.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SOUTHWEST COAST:
WNG: GALE.
WND: W25-35. 14/23Z W25. 15/23Z NW15-20.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SOUTH COAST:
WNG: NIL.
WND: SW25 LCLY G35 ALONG THE COAST. 15/01Z SW25. 15/08Z W25 XCPT W15 OVER NORTHERN SECTIONS.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SOUTHEASTERN GRAND BANKS:
WNG: NIL.
WND: SW15-20. 15/14Z W25.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SOUTHWESTERN GRAND BANKS:
WNG: NIL.
WND: W20. 15/05Z W25.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```